# Awkward Landscape keyboard in portrait mode, IOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

I have a portrait app that have Built-In `UIViewController` (portrait only) with the `UIWebView` that opens youtube video. Upon video playback user can rotate to landscape mode. After returning from video app correctly rotates to portrait but if user starts text editing - an awkward keyboard appears. I've tried adding landscape support to all screens - it doesn't solve the problem.

Simple steps are:

1. `UIViewController` (portrait only)
2. push `UIVIewController` (portrait
   only) with `UIWebView` (youtube video)
3. start video playback, go fullscreen, rotate landscape
4. press Done go back to first `UIViewController`
5. activate textField

[image]

Comment: Did you ever fix this?

Comment: I was offered this solution but i haven't really tested it
https://devforums.apple.com/thread/263822

Answer (score -1):

In swift:

```
 UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(1, forKey: "orientation")
 UIViewController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
```

By using this block in view will appear you solve this issue.